# How can I opimize the stored procedure in MySQL (Laravel)

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I want to optimize the stored procedure that is written in mysql combination of unions. It will take more 40 minutes to calculate. but excel takes 5 minutes to calculate its records.  [image]

```
BEGIN
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE panCrd VARCHAR(255);

DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT DISTINCT(bank_balance_card.pan) 
    FROM bank_balance_card 
    INNER JOIN bank_balance ON bank_balance.id = bank_balance_card.bank_balance_id 
    WHERE bank_balance.bankbal_date = reportDate
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT(daily_balance_shift.pan) 
    FROM daily_balance_shift 
    WHERE daily_balance_shift.repot_date = previousDate
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT(cardauthorisation.Card_PAN) 
    FROM cardauthorisation 
    WHERE cardauthorisation.SettlementDate = reportDate
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT(cardbaladjust.Card_PAN) 
    FROM cardbaladjust 
    WHERE cardbaladjust.SettlementDate = reportDate
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT(cardchrgbackrepres.Card_PAN) 
    FROM cardchrgbackrepres 
    WHERE cardchrgbackrepres.SettlementDate = reportDate
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT(cardevent.Card_PAN) 
    FROM cardevent 
    WHERE cardevent.Event_Date LIKE CONCAT(reportDate,"%")
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT(cardfee.Card_PAN) 
    FROM cardfee 
    WHERE cardfee.SettlementDate = reportDate
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT(cardfinancial.Card_PAN) 
    FROM cardfinancial 
    WHERE cardfinancial.SettlementDate = reportDate
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT(cardloadunload.Card_PAN) 
    FROM cardloadunload 
    WHERE cardloadunload.SettlementDate = reportDate
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT(agencybankingfee.Card_PAN) 
    FROM agencybankingfee 
    WHERE agencybankingfee.SettlementDate = reportDate
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT(agencybanking.Card_PAN) 
    FROM agencybanking 
    WHERE agencybanking.SettlementDate = reportDate;

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

    OPEN cur1;
    read_loop: LOOP
set done = false;
FETCH cur1 INTO panCrd;
IF done THEN
LEAVE read_loop;
END IF;
CALL openingAcBal(previousDate,panCrd,@opening_ac_bal1);
CALL prevtrans_settled(previousDate,panCrd,@prevTrans_settle);
IF (@prevTrans_settle IS NULL) THEN
SET @prevTrans_settle = 0;
END IF;
IF (@opening_ac_bal1 IS NULL) THEN
SET @opening_ac_bal1 = 0;
END IF;
CALL ATMSettled(startDate,endDate,panCrd,@ATM_Settled);
CALL POSSettled(startDate,endDate,panCrd,@POS_Settled);
CALL ATMFEE(startDate,endDate,panCrd,@ATM_FEE);
CALL FPIN(startDate,endDate,panCrd,@FPIN);
CALL BacsIN(startDate,endDate,panCrd,@BacsIN);
IF (@BacsIN IS NULL) THEN
SET @BacsIN = 0;
END IF;
CALL FPout(startDate,endDate,panCrd,@FP_out);
CALL ABDD(startDate,endDate,panCrd,@AB_DD);
IF (@AB_DD IS NULL) THEN
SET @AB_DD = 0;
END IF;
CALL FPoutfee(startDate,endDate,panCrd,@FP_out_fee);
CALL chargeBacks(startDate,endDate,panCrd,@charge_backs);
CALL RepresentmentsDs(startDate,endDate,panCrd,@representments);
CALL Otherfees(startDate,endDate,panCrd,@Other_fees);
CALL LoadUnload(startDate,endDate,panCrd,@Load_Unload);
CALL BalanceAdj(startDate,endDate,panCrd,@Balance_Adj);
CALL closingacbalgps(@clsbal,reportDate,panCrd);
IF (@clsbal IS NULL) THEN
SET @clsbal = 0;
END IF;
SET @clacbalcal = @opening_ac_bal1 - @ATM_Settled - @POS_Settled - @ATM_FEE + @FPIN + @BacsIN - @FP_out - @AB_DD - @FP_out_fee - @Other_fees + @Load_Unload + @Balance_Adj + @charge_backs - @representments;
SET @diffCheck = @clsbal - @clacbalcal;
SET @trans_settled_not_adj_gps = 0;
SET @trans_settled_not_adj_gps_2 = NULL;
SET @trans_adj_gps1 = 0;
IF (@prevTrans_settle > 0) THEN
SET @trans_settled_not_adj_gps = (-1 * @prevTrans_settle);
END IF;
IF (@prevTrans_settle < 0) THEN
SET @trans_settled_not_adj_gps = (-1 * @prevTrans_settle);
END IF;
SET @diffamt = 0;
SET @diffamt = @clacbalcal - @clsbal + @trans_settled_not_adj_gps;
SET @insertedId = NULL;
SELECT daily_balance_shift.id INTO @insertedId FROM daily_balance_shift WHERE daily_balance_shift.repot_date = reportDate AND daily_balance_shift.pan = panCrd;
IF (@insertedId IS NULL) THEN
SET @uniQueId = uuid();
INSERT INTO daily_balance_shift (id,repot_date,pan,opening_ac_bal,ATM_Settled,POS_Settled,ATM_FEE,FPIN,Bacs_IN,FP_out,AB_DD,FP_out_fee,charge_backs,representments,Other_fees,Load_Unload,Balance_Adj,closing_ac_bal_calc,closing_ac_bal_gps,trans_settled_not_adj_gps,trans_settled_not_adj_gps_2,diff) VALUES (@uniQueId,reportDate,panCrd,@opening_ac_bal1,@ATM_Settled,@POS_Settled,@ATM_FEE,@FPIN,@BacsIN,@FP_out,@AB_DD,@FP_out_fee,@charge_backs,@representments,@Other_fees,@Load_Unload,@Balance_Adj,@clacbalcal,@clsbal,@trans_settled_not_adj_gps,@trans_settled_not_adj_gps_2,@diffamt);
ELSE
UPDATE daily_balance_shift SET daily_balance_shift.opening_ac_bal = @opening_ac_bal1 , daily_balance_shift.ATM_Settled = @ATM_Settled , daily_balance_shift.POS_Settled = @POS_Settled , daily_balance_shift.ATM_FEE = @ATM_FEE , daily_balance_shift.FPIN = @FPIN ,daily_balance_shift.Bacs_IN = @BacsIN , daily_balance_shift.FP_out = @FP_out , daily_balance_shift.AB_DD = @AB_DD , daily_balance_shift.FP_out_fee = @FP_out_fee , daily_balance_shift.charge_backs = @charge_backs , daily_balance_shift.representments = @representments , daily_balance_shift.Other_fees = @Other_fees , daily_balance_shift.Load_Unload = @Load_Unload , daily_balance_shift.Balance_Adj = @Balance_Adj , daily_balance_shift.closing_ac_bal_calc = @clacbalcal , daily_balance_shift.closing_ac_bal_gps = @clsbal , daily_balance_shift.trans_settled_not_adj_gps = @trans_settled_not_adj_gps , daily_balance_shift.trans_settled_not_adj_gps_2 = @trans_settled_not_adj_gps_2 , daily_balance_shift.diff = @diffamt WHERE daily_balance_shift.id = @insertedId;
END IF;
END LOOP;
CLOSE cur1;
END
```

Comment: Please post your code as text. Even JARVIS cannot read it...

Comment: I have attached the code snippet as well

Comment: Thats what i was trying to say. Please post your code as text not as image. Its too much tough to read the code as text.

Comment: Store procedure is too long, :p

Comment: You may still post the code what you want to optimize.

Comment: how can i send a file to you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203463/discussion-between-kaleemullah-and-ankit-bajpai).

Comment: You are using 1 cursor and few proc calling here. You have to optimize the query and run time of all the procs getting called in this procedure.

Answer (score 0):

The final `SELECT .. IF .. INSERT .. ELSE UPDATE` smells a lot like the *single* query `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY ... UPDATE`.  Try to change to that.

Is it possible for each of the `PROCEDUREs` to take a *table* of values and act on them all at once, *not using a cursor*?  (Cursors are slow.)

Then chang the big `cursor .. UNION` into

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t (...)
     SELECT .. UNION .. SELECT ....
```

And give `t` to the procedures instead of a single @ variable.

Oh, it smells like your procedure *could be* functions?  They do some things and set the @ variable as an `OUT` parameter?

Please show us a couple of the procedures so we can get a feel for what they are doing.

Comment: Sir, this is very complex. It was in laravel 5.4 version. I started working on other features. Can you suggest a solution  except store procedure.  I do calculation in excel it takes 5 to 6 minutes. But it  takes 40 to 45 minutes in laravel.  Please suggest a solution.

Comment: @Kaleemullah - Doing batches of rows all at once is usually faster, sometimes more than 10 times as fast.  So, I need to get into your Stored Procs to do that.  What you currently have cannot be sped up much, if any.

Comment: Thanks. Your suggestion is highly appriciated.